# Why my website keeps requesting resources from server even after the website is fully loaded

Tags: web-performance, core-web-vitals

I am working on the web vitals for a website and I was checking the Chrome Developer Tools the Network tab.  The website loads fully, but I see that in the network tab, the server requests keep on increasing and the resources requested go up to 7.8MB and the website has a slider that keeps repeating in the network. How can I check why so many requests are made?

Here is the picture of the network tab of the website.
[image: Chrome dev tool network tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the resource names are `slide-X.jpg`. Without seeing the website or its code, I can only guess that there's a carousel on the page that cycles through images. If the images aren't cacheable, they'd continue to be loaded over the network. Otherwise if they are cacheable, I'd expect to see no network requests at all or at worst a 304 HTTP "Not Modified" response code.

So I'd recommend confirming what kinds of widgets are on the page like a carousel with repetitive behavior and checking the cache control headers of static content like images to avoid the need to load the images each time. Personally, I think carousels are bad UX so I'd even suggest you consider removing it all together! Regardless, you should still cache your content more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you so much Rick. This is very helpful. You are absolutely right this is becuase of carousel.